# Fill missing value based on previous values

Tags: r

I have the following vector:

```
v <- c(2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8L, NA)
```

How can I replace missing values with the value of the previous series + 1 so it becomes:

```
c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 9L)
```

Comment: did you [search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776135/last-observation-carried-forward-in-a-data-frame) or try something?

Comment: package `zoo`  has tools for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned, `zoo` has a last-observation-carried-forward function. We can add one to it:

```
library(zoo)
v2 <- na.locf(v) 
v2[is.na(v)] <- v2[is.na(v)] + 1L
#[1] 2 2 3 3 3 3 8 9
```

Comment: or in one line: `ifelse(is.na(v), na.locf(v) + 1L, v)`

Comment: Another option may be `cummax(pmax(pmin(v, lag(v)+1, na.rm=TRUE), 0, na.rm=TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

Its not pretty or efficient but it gets the answer you want. Hopefully someone else will be able to post some nicer code but this should get you started.

```
v <- c(2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8L, NA)
last <- NA
vec <- vector()
for (i in 1:length(v)) {
    cur <- v[i]
    if (! is.na(cur) ) {
        val <- cur
        last <- cur
    }
    else  val <- last + 1
    vec[i] <- val
}

vec
```

Comment: I should have been more specific. You are right, it is easy to do with a loop. Was wondering if there was an elegant solution with dplyr or another package.