# R: fill missing value with prior values

Tags: r, loops, missing-data

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
d <- data.frame(county = c("Abilene", rep(NA, 5), "Cook", rep(NA, 4), "Blah", NA, "Allegheny", rep(NA, 3)))

      county
1    Abilene
2       <NA>
3       <NA>
4       <NA>
5       <NA>
6       <NA>
7       Cook
8       <NA>
9       <NA>
10      <NA>
11      <NA>
12      Blah
13      <NA>
14 Allegheny
15      <NA>
16      <NA>
17      <NA>
```

I want to fill in the `<NA>` with the value of the previous non-missing county name. In other words, I want to end up with this:

```
  county
1       Abilene
2       Abilene
3       Abilene
4       Abilene
5       Abilene
6       Abilene
7       Cook
8       Cook
9       Cook
10      Cook
11      Cook
12      Blah
13      Blah
14      Allegheny
15      Allegheny
16      Allegheny
17      Allegheny
```

So far, I have been looping over every value in `d$county`, updating a temporary variable with the name of every non-empty county value, and refilling each cell. This is very slow with a large dataframe. I would prefer to do this in `dplyr`, though am open to any other solution as well.

Comment: Also relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776135/last-observation-carried-forward-in-a-data-frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tidyr` we can use `fill(data, vars)`:

```
library(tidyr)
fill(d, county)
```

Comment: FYI, `tidyr::fill()` is written in C++ and is, in my experience, orders of magnitude faster than doing the equivalent operation via an R loop.

Comment: @jdobres - in fairness nobody would ever do this in a standard R loop on large data, unless they were torturing themselves.

Comment: Depends on what one means by "large". I was doing a rolling fill operation on a small data set with about a dozen columns and around 100k rows, which I didn't think would take all that long. It took hours. `dplyr::fill()` did the same in seconds.

Comment: I mean, you wouldn't need to use a loop in base R to do this - something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/41752185/496803 would be much much more efficient (<1 sec for many million cases).

Answer (score 2):

We can use `na.locf`

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(d)
```

Comment: That is the accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value

Comment: @jogo I haven't checked the link while answering this