# Extrapollate rows from the last year available up until a given year

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table, extrapolation

I have the following data:

```
library(data.table)  
df <- fread(
    "A   B  C  D  E  F  iso   year   
    0   A   NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   2009   
    1   Y   NA  2  NA  NA  NLD   2010   
    0   Q   NA  3  NA  NA  AUS   2011   
    1   NA  NA  4  NA  NA  AUS   2012 
    0   0   NA  7  NA  NA  NLD   2011  
    0   NA  1   NA  1  NA  ECU   2009   
    1   NA  0   NA  2  0   ECU   2010    
    1   NA  0   NA  2  0   ECU   2011    
    0   NA  0   NA  3  2   BRA   2011   
    1   NA  0   NA  4  NA  BRA   2012",
    header = TRUE
)
```

I want to extrapolate for each country, the entry of the last year in the dataset,up to a particular year. For example, I want to use the last year for every country in `df` (NLD=2011, AUS=2012, BRA=2012, ECU=2011), to create entries up to 2014. In other words, I would like to make duplicates of those entries, but with the years changed, of the last available year up to 2014.

Desired output:

```
library(data.table)  
df <- fread(
    "A   B  C  D  E  F  iso   year   
    0   A   NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   2009   
    1   Y   NA  2  NA  NA  NLD   2010   
    0   Q   NA  3  NA  NA  AUS   2011   
    1   NA  NA  4  NA  NA  AUS   2012
    1   NA  NA  4  NA  NA  AUS   2013 
    1   NA  NA  4  NA  NA  AUS   2014    
    0   0   NA  7  NA  NA  NLD   2011  
    0   0   NA  7  NA  NA  NLD   2012 
    0   0   NA  7  NA  NA  NLD   2013 
    0   0   NA  7  NA  NA  NLD   2014 
    0   NA  1   NA  1  NA  ECU   2009   
    1   NA  0   NA  2  0   ECU   2010   
    0   NA  0   NA  3  0   BRA   2011   
    1   NA  0   NA  4  0   BRA   2011   
    1   NA  0   NA  2  0   ECU   2011   
    1   NA  0   NA  2  0   ECU   2012
    1   NA  0   NA  2  0   ECU   2013 
    1   NA  0   NA  2  0   ECU   2014    
    0   NA  0   NA  3  2   BRA   2011   
    1   NA  0   NA  4  NA  BRA   2012
    1   NA  0   NA  4  NA  BRA   2013
    1   NA  0   NA  4  NA  BRA   2014",
    header = TRUE
)
```

But I do not really know where to start. What would be the easiest way to do this?

EDIT: When testing on the actual data, I noticed I overlooked one aspect of the dataset when phrasing the question. In the acutal dataset there is one more unique aspects (column A) in the row apart from the year.

```
library(data.table)  
df <- fread(
    "A   B  C  D  E  F  iso   year   
    1   A   NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   2009   
    1   Y   NA  2  NA  NA  NLD   2010   
    1   Q   NA  3  NA  NA  AUS   2011   
    1   NA  NA  4  NA  NA  AUS   2012 
    1   0   NA  7  NA  NA  NLD   2011  
    1   NA  1   NA  1  NA  ECU   2009   
    1   NA  0   NA  2  0   ECU   2010    
    1   NA  0   NA  2  0   ECU   2011    
    1   NA  0   NA  3  2   BRA   2011   
    1   NA  0   NA  4  NA  BRA   2012
    0   A   NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   2009   
    0   Y   NA  2  NA  NA  NLD   2010   
    0   Q   NA  3  NA  NA  AUS   2011   
    0   NA  NA  4  NA  NA  AUS   2012 
    0   0   NA  7  NA  NA  NLD   2011  
    0   NA  1   NA  1  NA  ECU   2009   
    0   NA  0   NA  2  0   ECU   2010    
    0   NA  0   NA  2  0   ECU   2011    
    0   NA  0   NA  3  2   BRA   2011   
    0   NA  0   NA  4  NA  BRA   2012",
    header = TRUE
)
```

I have tried to adapt Ronak's result in this respect:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(iso, A) %>%
  slice(c(1:n(), rep(n(), 2014 - last(year)))) %>%
  mutate(year = first(year):2014)
###
df <- df %>%
  #If not arranged by year
  arrange(iso, year, A)
  group_by(iso) %>%
  complete(year = seq(min(year), 2014)) %>%
  fill(B:F)
```

The top code works, but on my actual data gives the error:

```
Error: Column `year` must be length 18 (the group size) or one, not 21
```

The bottom option gives the following error when applied to the example:

```
Error in group_by(iso) : object 'iso' not found
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - Fill missing dates by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633460/r-fill-missing-dates-by-group)

Comment: Yes, I did :Z. Your post is really asking two questions: how to complete sequence of contiguous values, and how to fill missing values with last value. Both of these questions have been asked and answered before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570024/r-fill-missing-value-with-prior-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replicate the last row, we can `group_by` `iso` and repeat the last row in each group

```
df %>%
  group_by(iso) %>%
  slice(c(1:n(), rep(n(), 2014 - last(year)))) %>%
  mutate(year = first(year):2014)
```

---

For the updated data, where `year` values are repeated

```
df %>%
  group_by(iso) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  slice(row, rep(n(), 2014 - last(year))) %>%
  mutate(year = c(year[1:max(row)], year[max(row)] + 1:(2014 - year[max(row)]))) %>%
  select(-row)

#       A B         C     D     E     F iso    year
#   <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr> <int>
# 1     1 Q        NA     3    NA    NA AUS    2011
# 2     1 NA       NA     4    NA    NA AUS    2012
# 3     0 Q        NA     3    NA    NA AUS    2011
# 4     0 NA       NA     4    NA    NA AUS    2012
# 5     0 NA       NA     4    NA    NA AUS    2013
# 6     0 NA       NA     4    NA    NA AUS    2014
# 7     1 NA        0    NA     3     2 BRA    2011
# 8     1 NA        0    NA     4    NA BRA    2012
# 9     0 NA        0    NA     3     2 BRA    2011
#10     0 NA        0    NA     4    NA BRA    2012
# … with 20 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ronak! When applying your solution to my actual data, I noticed I made a small mistake in my data example. I adapated your answer to it, but i am not completely succesful (see EDIT). Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: @Tom The issue is `year` column has duplicated values hence the values can't be replicated properly.  This part works correctly `df %>%
  group_by(iso) %>%
  slice(c(1:n(), rep(n(), 2014 - last(year))))` but assigning new years gives an error.

Comment: I cannot really figure out how to work around it.. Should I post a new question?

Comment: @Tom i have updated the answer. See if it works now ?

Comment: Hey Ronak, I have a small question about your answer. Should the part `group_by(iso) %>%` not be `group_by(iso, A) %>%`? In my actual data it  otherwise  just stops at the first value it encounters ( instead of doing the operation for each value of A). I have added the column, to the grouping and it seems to work.

Comment: Maybe one more thing haha.. I am trying to reverse your solution for dates before the first date until 2008 for example. I think the slice part should then become `slice(row, rep(n(), first(year)-2008 )) %>%` But I am not sure how the `mutate` part should look..

Comment: @Tom Do you want to repeat first line or the last line till 2008 ? To repeat first line you can do `df %>%
    group_by(iso) %>%
    slice(c(1:n(), rep(1, first(year) - 2008))) %>%
    arrange(iso, year) %>%
    mutate(year = 2008:last(year))`

Comment: The first one indeed, thanks! I think I am encountering a problem with the last line, because of different group sizes (in the actual data): `Error: Column "year" must be length 36 (the group size) or one, not 39`. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Do you have some missing years ? Say 2010, 2011, 2014 2015 etc ?

Comment: Most likely yes.. I first checked for double years (and removed them), but that did not solve the problem. It is quite a large dataset..

Comment: Try replacing the las `mutate` line with `mutate(year = c(2008:first(year), setdiff(year, first(year))))`