# How to replace N/A value with last no-N/A value of a data frame by column in R

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
var1   var2
a      1
b      NA
c      NA
d      2
e      NA
f      3
g      3
```

I need the following data frame

```
var1   var2
a      1
b      1
c      1
d      2
e      2
f      3
g      3
```

I need the way of replacing NA value with last no-NA value of the column var2.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7735647/5977215  ?, or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2776135/5977215 ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `fill` function from the `tidyr` package

```
library(tidyr)
df = df %>% fill(var2)
```

where `df` is the name of your dataframe.

Output:

```
var1 var2
a    1
b    1
c    1
d    2
e    2
f    3
g    3
```