# Replace NA with preceding character string in vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset where I want to replace NAs with the preceding character string:

```
d <- data.frame(X = c("one", NA, "two", NA, "three", NA), Y = c(1:6),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> d
      X Y
1   one 1
2  <NA> 2
3   two 3
4  <NA> 4
5 three 5
6  <NA> 6
```

I came up with the following solution which seems lousy somehow:

```
v <- c()

for (i in seq_along(1:nrow(d))){
  v[i] <- ifelse(is.na(d$X[i]) == TRUE, d$X[i-1], d$X[i])
}

d$X2 <- v    
d
      X Y    X2
1   one 1   one
2  <NA> 2   one
3   two 3   two
4  <NA> 4   two
5 three 5 three
6  <NA> 6 three
```

**My question:** Is there a better way to do this and how could this be implemented in a dplyr pipe?

Comment: You can create a column that is a lag of the X column using the dplyr lag and then you can use an ifelse and don't have to loop over it!

Comment: @d.b The documentation for `zoo::na.locf` gives a slightly more simplified version of this: `ave(x, cumsum(!is.na(x)), FUN = function(x) x[1])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing NAs with latest non-NA value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value) and [Last Observation Carried Forward In a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776135/last-observation-carried-forward-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tidyr` has a function `fill` that fills in `NA`s with the closest non-missing value above it.

If you're fine filling in values in `X` in place:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d %>%
  fill(X)
#>       X Y
#> 1   one 1
#> 2   one 2
#> 3   two 3
#> 4   two 4
#> 5 three 5
#> 6 three 6
```

Or if you need to keep the original `X` with its missing values, copy it over to another column, and fill that one in:

```r
d %>%
  mutate(X2 = X) %>%
  fill(X2)
#>       X Y    X2
#> 1   one 1   one
#> 2  <NA> 2   one
#> 3   two 3   two
#> 4  <NA> 4   two
#> 5 three 5 three
#> 6  <NA> 6 three
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this one? Simplifying your using `apply` family:
If you want to create a new column

```
d$X2 <- unlist(lapply(1:nrow(d), function(x){
                  ifelse(is.na(d[x,]$X), d[x-1,]$X, d[x,]$X)
                  }
       ))
```

If you just want to fill the original

```
d$X <- unlist(lapply(1:nrow(d), function(x){
                  ifelse(is.na(d[x,]$X), d[x-1,]$X, d[x,]$X)
                  }
       ))
```