# Avoiding a loop when entry i might take the value of entry i-1

Tags: r, loops

I have vectors with mostly `NA` entries. I want to replace every `NA` with that vector's preceding non-`NA` entry. Specifically, the first entry will always be a 1, followed by a bunch of `NA`s, which I want to replace with 1. The `i`th entry could be another numeric, let's say 2, followed by more `NA`s that I want to replace with 2. And so on. The loop below achieves this, but there has to be a more R way to do it, right? I wanted to vectorize with `ifelse()`, but I couldn't figure out how to replace the `i`th entry with the `i-1`th entry.

```
> vec <- rep(NA, 10)
> vec
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
> vec[1] <- 1; vec[4] <- 2; vec[7] <- 3
> vec
 [1]  1 NA NA  2 NA NA  3 NA NA NA
> for (i in 1:length(vec)) if (is.na(vec[i])) vec[i] <- vec[i-1]
> vec
 [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

Thanks!

If context helps, I am adjusting for stock splits from the WRDS database, which has a column that shows when and how a split occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is already implemented in package `zoo`, function `na.locf` (Last Observation Carried Forward). See also here: [Propagating data within a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782704/propagating-data-within-a-vector/1782785)

Comment: Thanks! (half the time the answer is already here... I just need to search the correct phrase)

Answer (score 1):

If you're adjusting for stock splits, maybe you could use `adjRatios` from the TTR package.  All the heavy lifting in done in C, so it is very fast.  See `adjustOHLC` for an example of how to use `adjRatios` to adjust your data.

```
> require(quantmod)
> getSymbols("IBM",from="1980-01-01")
[1] "IBM"
> spl <- getSplits("IBM",from="1980-01-01")
> div <- getDividends("IBM",from="1980-01-01")
> 
> head(spl)
           IBM.spl
1997-05-28     0.5
1999-05-27     0.5
> head(div)
            [,1]
1980-02-06 0.215
1980-05-08 0.215
1980-08-07 0.215
1980-11-05 0.215
1981-02-05 0.215
1981-05-07 0.215
> 
> adjusters <- adjRatios(spl, div, Cl(IBM))
> head(adjusters)
           Split       Div
1980-01-02  0.25 0.7510967
1980-01-03  0.25 0.7510967
1980-01-04  0.25 0.7510967
1980-01-07  0.25 0.7510967
1980-01-08  0.25 0.7510967
1980-01-09  0.25 0.7510967
```